# How can I record PageViews in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-blog

Is there an easy way to record pageviews in Umbraco? I want to show the number of times a blog post has been viewed.

Answer (score 1):

What about using Google Analytics for that task?
Otherwise, I am building a small CRM for Umbraco that registers the unique users that accesses to your pages.

Hope I helped you.

Regards,
Eduardo